# How to replace a variable value using sed in output of ls

Tags: bash, shell

i am trying to list out of 4 files(using ls) which are in some other directory.

```
 path=logs/gh/
 ls -lrt ${path}sample ${path}sample1                                                                                                           
-rw-r--r-- 1 29573 29573 0 Apr 13 10:18 logs/gh/sample                                                                                                
-rw-r--r-- 1 29573 29573 0 Apr 13 10:18 logs/gh/sample1
```

but i want to return output as below

```
ls -lrt ${path}sample ${path}sample1                                                                                                           
-rw-r--r-- 1 29573 29573 0 Apr 13 10:18 sample                                                                                                
-rw-r--r-- 1 29573 29573 0 Apr 13 10:18 sample1
```

i tried using sed to replace $path with null but no use

```
ls -lrt ${path}log.txt| sed "s/${path}//g"
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'
```

Please let me know how to acheive this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are `/` characters in `$path`, which confuses `sed`. You can use other delimiters in `sed`, though: `sed "s|${path}||g"`.

This runs the risk of `|` occurring in `$path`, even if it's unlikely.

Why not do this instead:

```
(cd logs/gh/; ls -lrt sample sample1)
```

The parentheses make the change of directory local to the commands within them.

Comment: How to store the output of (cd logs/gh/; ls -lrt sample sample1) to a variable and should preserve new lines

Comment: Thanks it worked i am able to store output in a variable

Answer (score 0):

Your original command is something like:

```
ls -lrt ${path}* | sed "s/${path}//g"
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'
```

the error can be suppressed by: (1) adding the `-n` option to `sed`, (2) replacing `/` with `|`, and (3) using `p` flag instead of `g`:

```
ls -lrt ${path}* | sed -n "s|${mypath}||p"
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't test it right now but try this:

```
cd ${path}sample && ls -lrt
```